# Graficar Highchart (column) desde consulta Linq

Tags: json, linq, asp.net-core

Si bien hay muchisimas preguntas, probé de todo y cada uno de los ejemplos pero no logro hacer funcionar lo que necesito.
Primero hago una consulta a la base de datos para que busque recibos emitidos durante el año a buscar agrupados por meses:
View donde elijo el año

```
<form asp-action="GraficarPorPeriodo" method="post">
<div class="form-group form-inline">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>Seleccione Período</label>
        <select class="form-control input-sm" asp-items="ViewBag.años" id="periodo" name="periodo"></select>
    </div>
</div>

<br />
<div class="form-group">
    <input class="btn btn-info" value="Graficar" type="submit" />
</div>
```

Luego ejecuto la consulta:

```
public IActionResult GraficarPorPeriodo(string periodo)
    {
        var cuenta = (from r in _context.Recibos
                      where r.Tipo == "Recibo"
                      && r.Fecha.Value.Year >= Convert.ToInt32(periodo)
                      && r.Fecha.Value.Year <= Convert.ToInt32(periodo)
                      select r).GroupBy(g => g.Fecha.Value.Month).Select(x => new
                      {
                          Cuenta = x.Count()

                      });

        List<int> Lista = new List<int>();
        foreach (var item in cuenta)
        {
            Lista.Add(item.Cuenta);
            //Lista.Add(string.Concat(","));
            //ViewData["cuenta"] = Lista;


        }

        return View(Lista);

    }
```

Y por último en el View tengo lo siguiente:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("/Recibos/GraficarPorPeriodo", function (data) {
            Highcharts.chart('chart', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Recibos'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: [
                        'Jun',
                        'Jul',
                        'Ago',
                        'Sep',
                        'Oct',
                        'Nov',
                        'Dic'
                    ],
                    crosshair: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Cantidad'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
                    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f}</b></td></tr>',
                    footerFormat: '</table>',
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Recibos',
                    data: data

                }]
            });
        });        

    });
```

Con esto únicamente consigo que la vista no tenga ningún gráfico. Probe cambiando con `return Json(Lista)` y solo me muestra los resultados JSON

```
[1,9,3]
```

¿Algún consejo?
Muchas gracias desde ya!

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude resolver. El problema lo tenia ya que en la misma vista que quería grafricar me traía el resultado JSON. Por lo que cree otro método para los resultados JSON y la vista quedo como cualquier otra:

Controlador:

```
public IActionResult GraficarPorPeriodo(string periodo)
    {
        TempData["periodo"] = periodo;
        TempData.Keep();
        return View();
    }
```

Le agregue un `TempData` para pasar el período seleccionado.

```
public IActionResult GetDataOpj ()
    {
        var periodo = TempData["periodo"];
        var cuenta = (from r in _context.Opjs
                      where (r.Presentacion.Value.Year >= Convert.ToInt32(periodo)
                      && r.Presentacion.Value.Year <= Convert.ToInt32(periodo)
                      )
                      select r).GroupBy(g => g.Presentacion.Value.Month).Select(x => new
                      {
                          Mes = x.Select(s => s.Presentacion.Value.Month).First(),
                          Cuenta = x.Count()

                      });

        return Json(cuenta);
    }
```

y en el View quedo de la siguiente forma

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("@Url.Action("GetDataOpj", "Informes")", function (data) {
            var cantidad = new Array();
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                cantidad.push(data[i].cuenta);
                //console.log(cantidad);

            }
            var categoriax = new Array();
            for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                categoriax.push(data[i].mes);
                //console.log(categoriax);

            }

            Highcharts.chart('columnaopj', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Ordenes de Pago | Pedidas por mes'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Mes'
                    },
                    categories: categoriax,
                    crosshair: true
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Cantidad'
                    }
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">Mes {point.key}</span><table>',
                    pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                    '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:1f}</b></td></tr>',
                    footerFormat: '</table>',
                    shared: true,
                    useHTML: true
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        pointPadding: 0.2,
                        borderWidth: 0
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Opj Pedidas',
                    data: cantidad

                }]
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Funciona a la perfección.

Saludos.